# Can 1password and lastpass coexist on the same machine and browser?

Tags: password-management, lastpass, 1password

We have users who have both Lastpass and 1Password accounts.  Can the users have both 1Password and Lastpass browser plugins installed on the same machine and browser?  And can they coexist or will problems arise?

EDIT: The users keep different accounts in Lastpass from those kept in 1Password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the users have both 1Password and Lastpass browser plugins installed on the same machine and browser?

Yes; Only one will actually fill the username/password fields out automatically depending on your user habits.

However, both support automatically filling out your fields that means you will have to make sure both have the correct password.

> And can they coexist or will problems arise?

They certainly can coexist but neither are specifically designed to do so.  So you will be prompted to save a password twice.  You will have to be logged into both accounts in order to keep your passwords synchronized

> The users keep different accounts in Lastpass from those kept in 1Password.

You will be prompted to save your password twice.  It will be up to the user to decide which one to use.